# Comma issue when exporting DataTable to CSV

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, csv, export-to-csv

I've adopted some code which converts a DataTable into a CSV file.  It seems to work well, except for when commas are used in the actual data.  Is there a way to display the comma in that case? This is what I've done:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

IEnumerable<string> columnNames = dtResults.Columns
                                           .Cast<DataColumn>()
                                           .Select(column => column.ColumnName);
sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", columnNames));

foreach (DataRow row in dtResults.Rows)
{
    IEnumerable<string> fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString());
    sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));
}

File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog.FileName, sb.ToString());
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Commas within CSV Data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123875/commas-within-csv-data)

Comment: Another possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/769621/dealing-with-commas-in-a-csv-file

Comment: `field.ToString()` can cause a `NullReferenceException`. Use `string.Join(",",row.ItemArray)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If a field contains a comma it should be put in double (or single) quotes.

You could use the [FileHelpers library](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/) to create your CSV file, it should take care of escaping properly.

In case you don't want to use the library, the essential bit is this: if you have a comma, you must put your field within quotes, e.g.

```
ID, NAME
1, "Doe, John"
2, 'Doe, Jane'
```

If your field includes quotes, you should escape them with an additional quote:

```
3, "Anakin ""Darth Vader"", Skywalker"
4, 'O''Connor, Sinead'
```

A possible solution:

```
static string CsvEscape(this string value) {
    if (value.Contains(",")) {
        return "\"" + value.Replace("\"", "\"\"") + "\"";
    }
    return value;
}
```

And then in your code:

```
IEnumerable<string> fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString().CsvEscape());
```

P.S: according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) there is no real csv specification, but [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) describes a format that is often used.

Comment: Or to save the `OP` changing to much of his code, use `@"\"" + field @"\""` in the select of fields? :)

Comment: @LukeHennerley - Could you kindly elaborate on that please? :)

Comment: @DotNET Should you have a situation in which you could have your seperator inside some data, you should wrap the data with double quotes `""`

Comment: @LukeHennerley But what if i've got `""` within the data too? :/

Comment: @DotNET: I expanded my answer a little.

Comment: Really a short and nice solution

Comment: My edit was rejected for some reason, so here comes a comment: You also need to escape a value beginning with a ". So change the **if** in **CsvEscape** this way: if (value.Contains(",") || (value.Length > 0 && value[0] == '\"')) {

Answer (score 0):

I published the below modified code which will help you.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            string[] val =  { "ramesh","suresh, Ganesh" };
            IEnumerable<string> columnNames = val;

            IList<string> objFinal = new List<string>();
            foreach (string v in columnNames)
            {
                string temp = v;
                if (temp.Contains(","))
                    temp = "\"" + v + "\"";

                objFinal.Add(temp);
            }
            sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", objFinal.AsEnumerable<string>()));

            }
```

The CSV supports the comma in data between the double codes.

You can append the double codes as well as comma in a single shot with help of the below single line of code

```
IEnumerable<string> columnNames = dtResults.Columns
                                           .Cast<DataColumn>()
                                           .Select(column => column.ColumnName);

var res = columnNames.Aggregate((current, next) => "\"" + current + "\"" + ", " + "\"" + next + "\"");


File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog.FileName, res.ToString());
```