# Datatable export to csv how to fix divde to two table when field has comma

Tags: jquery, datatable

Im using datatable, all working fine but Im facing problem when export to csv because I have address row which include comma (Chicago, IL) so when I export I get the field address divded into two fields

Address

[image]

But it must be when export, Chicago, IL or Chicago -IL but not to add another column with the part IL
so please how can I fix this issue

```
  buttons: [{
                    extend: "print",

                    className: "btn dark btn-outline"
                }, {
                    extend: "pdf",
                    className: "btn green btn-outline"
                }, {
                    extend: 'csvHtml5',
               exportOptions: {
                     columns: ['.export'],
                              },


               className: "btn-outline"
                }],
                language: {
                    lengthMenu: " _MENU_ records"
                },
```

Comment: Duplicate question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14937984/comma-issue-when-exporting-datatable-to-csv

Comment: No it is not duplicated