# Flat File to retain commas from SQL data

Tags: ssis

I’m importing a SQL view to SSIS using the Flat File Connection Manager. One of my columns in SQL has comma(s) in it. (123 Main St, Boston, MA) . When I import the data to SSIS, the commas within the column are being treated as delimiters, and my column is being broken into several columns. I have done a lot of research online, and have followed some workarounds which aren't working for me.

In SQL Server, I added double quotes around the values that have comma(s) in it.

```
' "'+CAST(a.Address as varchar(100))+'" '
```

So,  123 Main St, Boston, MA  now reads  “123 Main St, Boston, MA”

Then in my SSIS Flat File Connection Manager,

**In the General tab:**

- Text Qualifier is set to  “
- Header Row Delimiter is set to {CR}-{LF}

**In the columns tab:**

- Row delimiter is set to {LF}
- Column delimiter is set to Comma {,}

**And in the advanced Tab**, all of my columns have the Text Qualified set to True.

After all of this, my column with commas in it, is still being separated into multiple columns. Am I missing a step? How can I get the SSIS package to treat my address column as one column and not break it out to several columns?

**EDIT:** Just to add more specifics. I am pulling from a SQL view that has double quotes around any field that has commas in it. I am then emailing that file and opening it in MS Excel. When I open it the file it read as follows:

123 Main St       Boston       MA" " (In three cells)

And I need it to read as

123 Main St, Boston, MA (in one cell)

Comment: Do you have any white space between the column delimiters in your source file? Like: "column1",  "column2" , "column3"

Comment: A few questions - So you are writing from SQL table to a flat file using SSIS and then reading from the same flat file using SSIS to what? so after adding double quotes in your SQL by ' "'+CAST(a.Address as varchar(100))+'" '  are the double quotes showing up in the file? Why use the file intermediary when your SSIS can directly pull from SQL server?

Comment: as @TMNT2014 asked, what exactly you are trying to do.. what's your flow in package.

Comment: My flow is Ole DB source -> Flat file destination. In my sql view, my data has quotations around the columns that have commas in it. I am pulling data directly from SQL. The double quotes are showing up in the file.

Comment: Did you try re-pointing to the file in your connection manager and then resetting the columns?

Comment: @TMNT2014, I did try that.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look of this - [Commas within CSV Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123875/commas-within-csv-data)

> If there is a comma in a column then that column should be surrounded
>   by a single quote or double quote. Then if inside that column there is
>   a single or double quote it should have an escape charter before it,
>   usually a \
>
> Example format of CSV

```
ID - address - name 
1, "Some Address, Some Street, 10452", 'David  O\'Brian'
```

- Change every comma values with another unique delimiter which values haven't any of the characters inside,like : vertical bar ( | )
- Change column delimiter to this new delimiter , and set text qualifier with double quote ( " )
- You can automate the replace process using a Script Task before Dataflow Task for replacing delimiters. You can use [replace script form here.](http://www.rad.pasfu.com/index.php?/archives/13-Problem-with-comma-values-in-Comma-Delimited-File.html)

Also have a look of these resources.

- [Fixing comma problem in CSV file in SSIS](http://miky-schreiber.com/wordpress/?p=155)
- [How to handle extra comma inside double quotes while processing a CSV file in SSIS](http://ssisextracommainsidedoublequotes.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/how-to-handle-extra-comma-inside-double.html)

Comment: I am pulling data directly from a sql view

Answer (score 0):

I ended up recreating the package, using the same parameters that are listed in my question. I  also replaced this

```
' "'+CAST(a.Address as varchar(100))+'" '
```

with this in my SQL view

```
  a.Address
```

And it now runs as desired. Not sure what was going on there. Thanks to everyone for their comments and suggestions.