# Import CSV into SQL Server where one of the columns is JSON data

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv

Is there a way of importing CSV data into a SQL Server table where one of the columns contains JSON data?

An example CSV row might be the following:

```
1,{"testId": 2, "testName":"Hello!"},3,4,5
```

When I try to import this using the following SQL, it picks up the JSON commas as being delimeters

```sql
BULK INSERT TableName
FROM '<PathToCSV>'
WITH
(
  FIRSTROW = 1,
  FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
  ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0A',
  TABLOCK
)
```

Is there a way of intelligently filtering them out as literal commas rather than delimeters similar to how Excel handles it?

EDIT: Assume that its not feasible for me to edit the CSV's

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Commas within CSV Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123875/commas-within-csv-data)  Not sure if it will accept both a { and a } as the wrap character though

Comment: I solved this by using the "Import Flat File" feature in SSMS which I didn't realise existed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `CSV` format specifier, along with `FIELDQUOTE`, to ensure that quoted values are not broken up if they contain commas. This only works on SQL Server 2017 onwards.

```sql
BULK INSERT SchoolsTemp
FROM '<PathToCSV>'
WITH
(
    FORMAT = 'CSV', 
    FIELDQUOTE = '"',
    FIRSTROW = 1,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0A',
    TABLOCK
)
```

---

As for the JSON itelf, if need be you can shred that after importing using `OPENJSON`. For example

```sql
INSERT SomeTable (Column1, Column2, ParentId)
SELECT
  j.Column1,
  j.Column2,
  p.Id
FROM ParentTable p
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(p.YourJson)
  WITH (
    Column1 int,
    Column2 varchar(100)
  ) j;
```

Comment: Thank you! Just the first part was all I needed as I didn't need to parse the JSON through SQL, but the FORMAT='CSV' is great.